# How to automatically fill search in vfp

Tags: foxpro, searchbar

I want to insta search here like when i type the first letter and all of the words with those letters will pop up, then after i pressed search it will only display only the catname

[image: I want to insta search here like when i type the first letter and all of the words with those letters will pop up, then after i pressed search it will only display only the catname]

Comment: You can write your own utility in the InteractiveChange method of the Text1 textbox.  Whenever the Text1 value changes, the method runs.  It can 'examine' the new Text1 value and do whatever you need as a result.

Comment: But i dont know how the code exactly. But i used a listbox  and sql to load it. how should i do it on a textbox?

Comment: I guess that now is your opportunity to learn how to code.   Your Listbox requires a Source so you cannot eliminate its current source and replace it with another.  But you can run another query and get new results which can be appended to the original source.

Comment: Or, if the Textbox entries will diminish the items shown in the Listbox, you can use code in then Textbox's InteractiveChange method to modify the ListBox's Source table - after which you will want to do a ListBox.Refresh

Comment: If you are not familiar with the VFP language I'd suggest that you spend some time with the Free, On-line VFP Tutorial Videos at:   http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx